# Onto or not onto :$ f((m, n)) = (m^2)(n)$

Tags: combinatorics

Determine whether or not the function $f \colon \mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}$  is onto, if
$$f((m, n)) = m^2n$$

I know that onto means: for every element $b$, there is  a such that $f(a) = b$.
I just don't know how to apply that to this question. I also do not understand what $\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}$ is.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: $\mathbb{Z}$ represents the integers (positive, negative and zero).  $f : \mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}$ represents a function from ordered pairs of integers to integers.

Comment: Is (m^2)(n) something other than $\: m^{\hspace{.02 in}2}\hspace{-0.045 in}\cdot \hspace{-0.03 in}n \;$? $\;\;\;\;$

Comment: no it translates to what you just posted. m times m times n

Comment: Don't forget to click the check mark underneath the upvote arrows for the answer you decide to accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$ Means the set of all ordered pairs $(a,b)$ with $a$ and $b$ being integers and $\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{Z}$ means the function goes from the set of ordered pairs of integers to just the integers. As for wether or not it is surjective (as I loath onto), iti s fairly easy, let $b$ be a given integer, does there exist $m^2n=b$? Yes, $n=b$ and $m=1$, we then have $1^2b=b$ and we have $f(1,b)=b$

Answer (score 3):

Yes this function is onto as any element $b$ in $\mathbb{Z}$ has the preimage $(1, b)\in \mathbb{ZxZ}$ i.e. $b=1^2b$.

Comment: You deserve a +1 for showing some thing is onto, Sir Jective !

Comment: Relevant username :D

Comment: Lol I just realized what I just did. Quite epic if I do say so myself.